# Compiling android app source code + code check

Tags: android

I'm totally newbee regarding APK and android stuff, so any suggestion is welcome.

I'm trying to install and test the source code from this link:
http://sanjosetech.blogspot.hr/2013/03/gstreamer-streaming-video-and.html

The code should load audio and video passed from RPI to my android phone.
I have RPI part ready and it's working, now i need to compile and install this updated version so i can have support for audio and video.

If i download this code directly on my phone (over my mail account), how can i compile and run it ?

Best regards !

Answer (score 0):

You have to build code into APK file, using compiler, [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html), for example. And then transfer it to your Android device.